# React props undefined on receiving

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm having this issue with passing props object that on second page it says it's undefined. I tried if I'm passing it correctly with **console.log(databaseObject?.points[0].questions)** on first page and it was what I wanted, but when I tried to receive it on second page it's always undefined. Am I missing something on receiving the props or? On second page from **console.log(props.questions)** I got 'undefined' and from **console.log(Object.values(props.questions))** I got TypeError: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

first.tsx

```
interface Point {
  details: string,
  id: string,
  image: string,
  imagePath: number,
  isFirst: boolean,
  isLast: boolean,
  isReady: boolean,
  poiont: object,
  pointTitle: string,
  questions: Question[]
}

interface Question {
  answer1: string,
  answer2: string,
  answer3: string,
  id: string,
  question: string,
  rightAnswer: string
}

interface DatabaseObject {
  points: Point[]
  trailId: string
}
```

Code below is to redirect to second page

```
  const redirect = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: '/user_app/quiz',
      state: databaseObject?.points[0].questions
    });
  }
```

second.tsx

```
interface Question {
    answer1: string,
    answer2: string,
    answer3: string,
    id: string,
    question: string,
    rightAnswer: string
  }

interface Props {
    questions: Question[]
  }


const QuizPage: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) =>{
    const history = useHistory();
    const [answered, setAnswered] = useState(false);
    const [correct, setCorrect] = useState(false);
    const [clickedAnswer, setClickedAnswer] = useState('');
    const coreectAnswer = 'odpoved1'

    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log(props.questions)
        console.log(Object.values(props.questions))
        checkAnswer()
    })
```

Comment: Can you show us where you render the `<QuizPage>`, so we can see how the prop is being passed in?

Comment: `state` is part of `props.location`, i.e. `props.location.state`.

Comment: @morganney thank you, it worked, because I'm passing the props through history.push

Comment: @Miko great. If you don't mind can you accept my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed a `location` object to [`history.push`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history) so the component can find the corresponding `state` there.

```js
useEffect(() =>{
  console.log(props.location.state.questions)
  console.log(Object.values(props.location.state.questions))
  checkAnswer()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`props` is not available in `useEffect` scope.
You must pass it as a dependency in `useEffect`.

Try following:

```
 useEffect(() =>{
        console.log(props.questions)
        console.log(Object.values(props.questions))
        checkAnswer()
    }, [props])
```